# initializing references in c++ doesn't work but initializing const references works, why?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

```
const string& s = "rajat";
```

works while

```
string& s = "rajat";
```

doesn't. Why?

Comment: Only const lvalue references can bind to temporary/r-values.

Comment: Because you forgot to read all the existing material available on the subject.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : that's why I'm asking it here.

Comment: @prongs: You're expected to read the existing material available on the subject first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"rajat"` is not a `std::string`, it is a null-terminated array of six `char`, i.e. `char[6]`

You can construct a `std::string` from a null-terminated array of `char`, and that's what happens when you write:

```
std::string s = "rajat";
```

When you want to initialize a `string&` you have to have a `string` for the reference to bind to, so the compiler tries to construct a `string` from the `char` array and bind the reference to that i.e.

```
std::string& s = std::string("rajat");
```

However this is illegal because the `string` that gets constructed is a temporary object and non-const references cannot bind to temporary objects, see [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565600/981959)

Answer (score 2):

This will implicitly construct a temporary `string` from the string literal on the RHS. The temporary is then bound to a reference:

```
const string& s = "rajat";
//                 ^^^^^ temporary string is constructed from "rajat" literal
```

The language only allows `const` references to bind to temporaries, so this

```
string& s = "rajat";
```

is illegal, since it attempts to bind a non-const reference to a temporary `string`.

See this related [GotW post](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/), which also deals with lifetime issues.